# Are questions asking general solutions of a scenario but no actual codes on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Sometimes I can see OP is posting a scenario as question and hope to have general solution or main idea about the scenario like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397939).

But the problem is, their questions and answers does not contain any actual codes, is that still "specific" enough to be on topic here?

Comment: Looks a bit _too broad_ for my taste. But the OP provided some approaches at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP asks:

> **what method do you think is the best** to choose for a banner? **which is better** for speed, for your site, for SEO, for google, for anything

This question should be closed as **primarily opinion-based**:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.